# Add text to the progressbar in jQuery

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, caption

Is there some tweak to add a caption to the progressbar control? I'd love to put a centered caption which displays current percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a `<div>` with some styling to get a centered caption underneath, like this:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 37
}).append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");​​​​​​​​​​
```

And some CSS:

```
​#progressbar .caption​ { width: 50px; margin: 0 auto; }​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/DVGnn/), just use `$("#progressbar .caption").html(value)` to update it.

Answer (score 3):

This is more a CSS question. I've gotten the label to be centered directly over the progress bar. The way I've done it is to:

Wrap your progress bar code in a `div` with a clearing `div` at the end of the container. Then, prepend your label in the container and `float` it to the left. Add some space in the label so it's not touching the side of the progress bar:

```
<div id='pb_container'>
    <div style='float: left' id='label'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Label</div>
    <div id='pb'></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Instantiate the progress bar and the label should be floating in the progress bar, to the left a little. You will have to play with padding and width/height of the elements to get it to float where you want it. (Like the center of the bar, for example)

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Vq/). As you can see from my CSS code, it takes a little fiddling to center it just right, but it looks nice.

Comment: fyi, the link above seems to point at the wrong code (same code as the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's quite simple:

```
<div id="progressBar" class="progressBar">
    <span class="progressBarText">In Progress</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progressBar {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
}
.progressBarText {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left:25%;
}
<script>
$('#progressBar').progressbar(
            {
                value: 80

            });
</script>
```